# Import-SPWeb Issue

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, powershell

I’m trying to move a subsite in another site collection.
 I follow this article:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/356985/Moving-a-Sharepoint-Sub-Site-to-its-own-Site-Colle

Export works fine, but import doesn't; I receive this error:

```
 [11/6/2013 10:54:48 AM] [File] [GettingStarted.aspx] Progress: Importing
 [11/6/2013 10:54:48 AM] [File] [GettingStarted.aspx]   Verbose: Source URL: GettingStarted.aspx
 [11/6/2013 10:54:48 AM] [File] [GettingStarted.aspx]   Verbose: Destination URL: /sites/itc/GettingStarted.aspx
 [11/6/2013 10:54:48 AM] [File] [GettingStarted.aspx]   Progress: Importing web parts
 [11/6/2013 10:54:48 AM] FatalError: The element 'WebPart' in namespace 'urn:deployment-manifest-schema' has invalid child element 'ParameterBinding' in namespace 'urn:deployment-manifest-schema'. List of possible elements expected: 'Script, PagedRowset, PagedClientCallbackRowset, PagedRecurrenceRowset, ViewFields, ViewData, Query, RowLimit, RowLimitExceeded, Toolbar, Formats, Aggregations, List, MetaData, View, ViewStyle, ViewBody, ViewEmpty, ViewFooter, ViewHeader, ViewBidiHeader, GroupByFooter, GroupByHeader, CalendarViewStyles, CalendarSettings, ListFormBody, Xsl, XslLink, JS, JSLink, ParameterBindings, OpenApplicationExtension, Mobile, MobileItemLimit, Method, WebParts, InlineEdit, Joins, ProjectedFields' in namespace 'urn:deployment-manifest-schema'.
 [11/6/2013 10:54:48 AM] Debug:    at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidator.SendValidationEvent(ValidationEventHandler eventHandler, Object sender, XmlSchemaValidationException e, XmlSeverityType severity)
    at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidator.ValidateElementContext(XmlQualifiedName elementName, Boolean& invalidElementInContext)
    at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidator.ValidateElement(String localName, String namespaceUri, XmlSchemaInfo schemaInfo, String xsiType, String xsiNil, String xsiSchemaLocation, String xsiNoNamespaceSchemaLocation)
    at System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.ProcessElementEvent()
    at System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.Read()
    at System.Xml.XmlWriter.WriteNode(XmlReader reader, Boolean defattr)
    at System.Xml.XmlReader.ReadOuterXml()
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.XmlFormatter.ParseObject(Type objectType, Boolean isChildObject)
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.XmlFormatter.DeserializeObject(Type objectType, Boolean isChildObject, DeploymentObject envelope)
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.XmlFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream)
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ObjectSerializer.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream)
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPImport.DeserializeObjects()
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPImport.Run()
 [11/6/2013 10:55:00 AM] Progress: Import did not complete.
 [11/6/2013 10:55:00 AM] Finish Time: 11/6/2013 10:55:00 AM.
 [11/6/2013 10:55:00 AM] Duration: 00:00:41
 [11/6/2013 10:55:00 AM] Finished with 0 warnings.
 [11/6/2013 10:55:00 AM] Finished with 1 errors.
```

my SharePoint version is 15.0.4481.1005

Answer (score 2):

You have missed to activate some site collection level feature.

Go to your new **Site collection -> Site actions -> Site settings -> Site collection features**.

and compare with you old site collections features.

Comment: I deleted the new site collection, then I recreated it.
I activated all site collection features that were active in the old site.
Idem for the web features.
Then I rerun the command Import-SPWeb but I’m receiving the same error.

Comment: I compared features with tool "FeatureAdmin2013". All features of the old site are active in the new site.